Argue for changing the sum of a double sequence into the sum of a sequence
Let's say I have a nonnegative, double-indexed sequence (like a table extending to infinity in two directions) $(a_{ij})_{i,j\in \mathbb{N}}$, and assume $\sum_{j}a_{ij}=1/2^{i}$.
By theorem 8.3, Rudin's PMA, we know $\sum_{j}\sum_{i}a_{ij} = \sum_{i}\sum_{j}a_{ij} = 1$. Rudin's theorem 3.55 also says, if series $\sum s_{n}$ converges absolutely, then any rearrangement of it converges to the same limit.
Now lets do the "diagonal trick" and convert the double-indexed sequence $(a_{ij})$ into just a normal sequence $(a_{n})$. Is there a way we can show that $\sum a_{n}$ converges to 1?
I’m actually reviewing measure theory with Donald Cohn’s book. And on page 14, line 8, the author finds the cover of sets $A_{n}$, i.e., $\{I_{n,i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. He does the diagonal trick for indices $n, i$ and turns this sequence of covers $(\{I_{n,i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty})_{n}$ for $(A_{n})$ into a cover for $\cup A_{n}$ with just a single index, i.e., a cover $\{I_{m}\}$. Then he sums up volumes of intervals in this cover. It seems he assumes the sum of the doubly indexed sequence is the same as the sum of the sequence.

Can you elaborate on the "diagonal trick"? Are you saying that "Let $b_i = a_{i, i}$, then $\sum b_i = 1$? If so, that need not be true for a general $a_{i, j}$. EG Let $a_{i, j} = 1$ for $ i = j$ and 0 otherwise.

@CalvinLin I mean rearranging the doubly indexed sequence into a sequence this way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528700/walter-rudins-proof-countable-union-of-countable-sets-is-countable

Addendum added to respond to the comment question of Tom


...and convert the double-indexed sequence $(a_{ij})$ into just a normal sequence $(a_{n})$. Is there a way we can show that $\sum a_{n}$ converges to 1?

Alternative approach:
By definition,
$$\sum_{i,j \in \Bbb{N}} a_{ij} = \sum_{i\in \Bbb{N}} \left[ ~\sum_{j\in \Bbb{N}} a_{ij} ~\right].$$
From the premise, this simplifies to
$$\sum_{i\in \Bbb{N}} \left[ ~2^{-i} ~\right] = 1.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

RHS causes no ambiguity when, for example, each sum inside the square braces is nonnegative. But LHS doesn't specify the order of the summation.

You are given that the sequence is non-negative.  This implies that the terms in the sequence may be re-ordered, without affecting whether the sequence is convergent, or (if convergent) what the sequence's limit is.
The original specification $~\sum_{i,j \in \Bbb{N}} a_{ij}~$ requires that each ordered pair $~(i,j) \in [ ~\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N} ~]~$ be used to construct exactly one term $~a_{ij}.~$
Since it is given that each term of the sequence is non-negative, any re-ordering of the terms in the sequence that respects the constraint in the previous paragraph must be valid.
Note that if it was not given that every term in the sequence was non-negative, then this entire response would not be valid.
The following re-ordering does in fact respect the pertinent constraint:
$$\sum_{i\in \Bbb{N}} \left[ ~\sum_{j\in \Bbb{N}} a_{ij} ~\right]. \tag1 $$
Note that the alternative re-ordering below would similarly be valid:
$$\sum_{j\in \Bbb{N}} \left[ ~\sum_{i\in \Bbb{N}} a_{ij} ~\right]. \tag2 $$
However, the (valid) re-ordering in (1) above is more convenient to the problem, given the problem's premises.

Thank you! But does everyone agree with this definition? RHS causes no ambiguity when, for example, each sum inside the square braces is nonnegative. But LHS doesn't specify the order of the summation.

@Tom See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

appreciate your help!

Let $f :\mathbb{N} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection. Denote the sequence $a_{f(n)}$ by $b_{n}$. We want to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n} = 1$. Denote $f(n)=(x_{n}, y_{n})$.
Let the partial sums be $p_{m} := \sum_{n=1}^{m}b_{n}$. It's easy to see each $p_{m}$ is upper bounded by $1$. (Otherwise, it would contradict the fact that $\sum_{i}\sum_{j}a_{ij}=1$.
Recall the value of a series whose terms are nonnegative is the supremum (also the limit, as the partial sums are increasing) of its partial sums. So we still have to show that $1$ is the least upper bound of $\{p_{m}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$.
Let $\mathbb{I}$ denote the indicator function. Pick $0 < \epsilon < 1$. There is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{N} 1/2^{i} > 1-\epsilon/2$. Also, there is an $M$ such that if $m > M$, then $\{b_{1}, ..., b_{m}\}$ contains enough terms from $\{a_{i, j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that $1/2^{i} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{m}b_{n}\mathbb{I}\{x_{n}=i\} > 1/2^{i}-\epsilon/2N$, for any $i \in \{1, 2, ..., N\}$. Therefore, for $m>M$, $\sum_{n=1}^{m}b_{n} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{m}b_{n}(\mathbb{I}\{x_{n}=1\}+\mathbb{I}\{x_{n}=2\}+...+\mathbb{I}\{x_{n}=N\}) > \sum_{i=1}^{N}(1/2^{i}-\epsilon/2N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}(1/2^{i}) - \epsilon/2 > 1-\epsilon$.
This shows $1$ is the limit of $\{p_{m}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ and hence the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$.
